# How do i create dynamic div element using WEB WORKER in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have a project where I need to create a thousands of *DIV* elements when I first load the index, I tried WEB Workers so that my loading time can be saved a bit.

I am not able to create an Dynamic *Div* Element where I need to append it to some other *div* here is an short example what I am trying to do!

**index.html**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(typeof(Worker)!=="undefined"){
    // Web worker support!enter code here
    if(typeof(w)=="undefined"){
      w=new Worker("js/WW.js");
    }else{
      //re-utilizing the same worker.
    }
  }else{
    // Sorry! No Web Worker support..
  } 
});
</script>
```

**WW.js**

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
  var a=document.createElement("div");
}
```

If web workers cannot solve my problem can anyone let me know any other Approach?

Comment: You can't access `window.document` inside a web worker.

Comment: i have read about the same and also not Webworker not accessing any other element li navigator, window, etc but any solution or with the help of importScripts????

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data generated in the worker thread via message (event):

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
  self.postMessage('<div>' + i + '</div>');
}
```

And add event listener in the document:

```
  w = new Worker("js/WW.js");
  w.addEventListener('message', 
    function(e) { $('#result').append($(e.data)); }, 
    false
  );
```

I never used this in production, but the test works fine.

Comment: Mrak Thanks for the code but will it work faster than what it regularly takes?

Comment: This is the only way to pass the data from worker thread back to the document: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Passing_data

Comment: Again i am grateful to you mark it runs great divs are too created,  but yet m facing the following error.  

TypeError: Not enough arguments to Window.postMessage.
 

self.postMessage('<div>' + i + '</div>');

Comment: How do you run it? You are calling not a WebWorker's postMessage but window's (DOM) postMessage.

Comment: w = new Worker("js/WW.js");    w.addEventListener('message',function(e){    $('#result').append($(e.data)); 
}, false);)   ----- This is in index.html && ------ for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
  self.postMessage('<div>' + i + '</div>');
} ------ in is in my WW.js which is an Web Worker yet it is throwing an Error in Firefox.

Comment: What I left out in the example: You need jQuery and an empty div with id 'result'.

Comment: Thanks @mrak i hadn't removed the included JS for Webworker. its working abs fine thank again.

Comment: Can you please also let me know how can i append the parsed XML text in it using same Web Worker?